# Why does Entity Framework select all tables, columns and other info

Tags: entity-framework

After using the profiler we noticed that our application loads slower because of a query that Entity Framework executes.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[TABLE_NAME] AS [TABLE_NAME], 
    [Extent1].[COLUMN_NAME] AS [COLUMN_NAME], 
    [Extent1].[TABLE_CATALOG] AS [TABLE_CATALOG], 
    [Extent1].[TABLE_SCHEMA] AS [TABLE_SCHEMA], 
    [Extent1].[ORDINAL_POSITION] AS [ORDINAL_POSITION], 
    [Extent1].[COLUMN_DEFAULT] AS [COLUMN_DEFAULT], 
    [Extent1].[IS_NULLABLE] AS [IS_NULLABLE], 
    [Extent1].[DATA_TYPE] AS [DATA_TYPE], 
    [Extent1].[CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH] AS [CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH], 
    [Extent1].[CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH] AS [CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH], 
    [Extent1].[NUMERIC_PRECISION] AS [NUMERIC_PRECISION], 
    [Extent1].[NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX] AS [NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX], 
    [Extent1].[NUMERIC_SCALE] AS [NUMERIC_SCALE], 
    [Extent1].[DATETIME_PRECISION] AS [DATETIME_PRECISION], 
    [Extent1].[CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG] AS [CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG], 
    [Extent1].[CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA] AS [CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA], 
    [Extent1].[CHARACTER_SET_NAME] AS [CHARACTER_SET_NAME], 
    [Extent1].[COLLATION_CATALOG] AS [COLLATION_CATALOG], 
    [Extent1].[COLLATION_SCHEMA] AS [COLLATION_SCHEMA], 
    [Extent1].[COLLATION_NAME] AS [COLLATION_NAME], 
    [Extent1].[DOMAIN_CATALOG] AS [DOMAIN_CATALOG], 
    [Extent1].[DOMAIN_SCHEMA] AS [DOMAIN_SCHEMA], 
    [Extent1].[DOMAIN_NAME] AS [DOMAIN_NAME]
FROM [information_schema].[columns] AS [Extent1]
```

So this query gets all the information about the database. But we're wondering why and if it is possible to stop it or make it faster.

Comment: Please show us the correspoding call that results in this query.

Comment: Well that's the problem. We don't really think it's something we do, it's something EF does by itself when our program starts.

Comment: Can it be due to model compatibility checking? You can disable it using: `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);`

Comment: it actually needs to check and migrate the database whenever a database query gets actually executed, so on your first database call essentially, depending on your database initializer, it will use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables and Columns to match your POCO classes and database table on either of CreateDatabaseIfNotExists, DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges or DropCreateDatabaseAlways. Only on null initializer or of empty initializers derived own initializers EF does not need to check, but this could lead to mapping errors on runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way the EF is making sure that the model in the app is valid and the model schema is in sync with the DB schema. EF just works this way